# OPTIONS request inconsistency (in deployment)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

## Introduction

So, I'm using the MERN stack (with Heroku + Netlify), and I'm having some really strange consistency problems with how the DELETE request is being handled. I've tried countless solutions in the last
three days trying to get this to work and none of them have worked. A lot of these solutions have
come from stack overflow, so if you want to direct me to another post, the chance is that I've already seen it. I've scoured every part of the web and making this post is my last resort.

## The Problem

So, when I make a delete request, I'm getting the per-usual OPTIONS request since I'm sending a token in a custom header of the request ('x-auth-token'). The OPTIONS request always resolves with a 204, meaning that everything should be alright. However, afterward, there is no DELETE request like there should be. This, in essence, is my problem. I've checked my Heroku logs, and all I can see is the OPTIONS request, and nothing else.

### Inconsistencies?

So this is where I've been very confused. The thing is, that sometimes it DOES work. And other routes I use in my API (like login, and creating a new post) work, even though I'm using the same middleware.
Every time it works, I get the OPTIONS request and then the DELETE request (with a 200 status) like I would expect to happen.

**If you want an example of a re-creatable scenario:**

I create X number posts after logging in and getting a valid token, then I can see those posts rendering in the posts listing on my home page. I then navigate one of the posts and delete it by clicking and then a confirmation button. I automatically get redirected to the next post in the list. I repeat this till I get to the last post. I delete that post, and since there are no more posts left, I get redirected to the posts listing which is... not empty! The last post I tried deleting is still there.

Keep in mind, that the DELETE requests all get sent in exactly the same way, so I'm pretty sure this isn't a front-end issue, so no need to poke around in the code there. I've logged everything and debugged, and it's 100% consistent with what I would expect.

*(The create post doesn't redirect, while the delete post does? I don't see how this would effect anythign as the DELETE request gets sent as per usual... Though maybe a solution lies within this fact.)*

### Solutions I've tried

#### Cors

First off, you might already be rushing to your keyboard to tell me that this is a CORS issue. I thought the same thing yesterday, but I'm not so sure now. I've tried messing with all the config settings possible in CORS to get this to work. Since my two websites are on different domains, then CORS verifies the requests. I've already added my front-end website to a whitelist, and all other requests are going through properly, so no problem there. I've tried adding an allowHeaders option in the config, but it didn't do anything more than the default setting. I've also added 'OPTIONS' to the allowed methods in the config, still nothing. I'm also using app.use(cors({config})). I'll include some code later to see some more of this in detail.

#### Debugging

I've basically tested things out by inserting console.logs everywhere and discovered that neither the middleware, the options route (I tried making an options route with same route url), or the original post route get executed when the OPTIONS request doesn't result in a DELETE request.

#### Static Server

This is maybe where some of my inexperience shows (this is my first Web project). I saw some solutions telling that a static server is needed. So I tried setting up a static server, but I didn't see any results. So I'm not too sure what this accomplished.

#### Async and Await

I was just trying things at this point, so I made all my routes async to see if it would do anything. It didn't.

#### Others

I've also messed around with environment variables and dotenv, and other stuff I can't remember. I think everything here should already be sufficient information understand the situation.

## Code

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require("./routes/router");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require('morgan')

const app = express();

const whitelist = [
    process.env.ORIGIN
];

app.use(
cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            console.log(origin);
            callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
        }
    }, //frontend server localhost:3000
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    credentials: true, // enable set cookie
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));



mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('connected to db');
});

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String
});

// Routes
// TODO: make seperate routers/routes
app.use("/", routes);

// Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

// TODO: set up custom port in future
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`));
// Callback functions?
```

router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require('../models/Post');
const User = require('../models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const adminAuth = require('../middleware/adminAuth');
const cors = require("cors");

require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });
// import 'moment'

// second onwards are handlers => triggers like the post body then next() to go to the next handler
router.post('/api/add_post', adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
    
    newPost = new Post({
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body,
      author: req.body.author,
      created: req.body.created,
    });

    const savedPost = await newPost.save();
    if (!savedUser) throw Error('Something went wrong saving the post');
    res.send(savedPost);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message });
  }
    
});

router.delete('/api/delete_post/:id', adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
  // timeout?
  // console.log(req.body);
  try{
    const id = req.params.id;
    if(!id) throw Error('Invalid ID');
    const post = await Post.findById(id);
    if (!post) throw Error('Post doesn\'t exist');
    const removed = await post.remove();
    if(!removed) throw Error('Problem with deleting the post');
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Error: ", e.message);
    res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message, success: false });
  }
  
});


// TODO : UPDATE for async soon
router.post('/api/update_post', adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.body._id;
  test_post_data = {
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body,
      author: req.body.author,
      modified: req.body.modified,
  };
  console.log(test_post_data, id);
  Post.updateOne({ _id: id }, test_post_data, (err) => {
      if(err) return next(err);
      return res.status(200);
  });
});

router.get('/api/get_posts', async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
    const posts = await Post.find();
    if(!posts) throw Error('Error with fetching the posts')
    res.send(posts.reverse());
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message });
  }
});

router.get('/api/get_chapter/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
    const id = req.params.id;
    const post = await Post.findOne({_id: id})
    if(!post) throw Error('No post was found')
    res.send(post);
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message })
  }
    
});



// User routes
// TODO : make in seperate file

  router.post('/api/user/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  
    // Simple validation
    if (!name || !email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
    }
  
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (user) throw Error('User already exists');
  
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      if (!salt) throw Error('Something went wrong with bcrypt');
  
      const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      if (!hash) throw Error('Something went wrong hashing the password');
  
      const newUser = new User({
        name,
        email,
        password: hash,
        admin: false
      });
  
      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      if (!savedUser) throw Error('Something went wrong saving the user');
      

      // TODO : check up on expires stuff : 3600 = 1 hr
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: savedUser._id, admin: savedUser.admin }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: 3600
      });
  
      res.status(200).json({
        token,
        user: {
          id: savedUser.id,
          name: savedUser.name,
          email: savedUser.email,
          admin: savedUser.admin
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: e.message });
    }
  });

  router.post('/api/user/login', async (req, res) => {

    const { name, password } = req.body;
  
    // Simple validation
    if (!name || !password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
    }
  
    try {
      // Check for existing user
      const user = await User.findOne({ name });
      if (!user) throw Error('User Does not exist');
  
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch) throw Error('Invalid credentials');
  
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, admin: user.admin }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: 3600 });
      if (!token) throw Error('Couldnt sign the token');
  
      res.status(200).json({
        token,
        user: {
          id: user._id,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          admin: user.admin
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message });
    }
  });


module.exports = router;
```

adminAuth.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.header('x-auth-token'));
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  // Check for token
  if (!token)
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorizaton denied' });

  try {
    // Verify token
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    console.log('decoded:', decoded);
    
    if(!decoded.admin)
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Not an admin, authorization denied' });

    // Add user from payload
    // console.log('decoded:', decoded);
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' });
  }
};
```

Link for request examples, and Heroku log since Stackoverflow says it's spam:
https://gist.github.com/macklinhrw/b2fec97642882ba406c49cce3e195c39

**Edit**

[image: What I see in Chrome network trace]

I pasted the Chrome request and response headers into the gist at the bottom, but there was no response data to go along with either.

I've debugged a little using this to check the difference and I discovered that with delete action that ends up working, the red (canceled) request has headers, while the non-working is completely empty (filled with 'provisional headers' if that means anything).

I couldn't copy-paste the request headers into the gist for the working red (canceled) one. But, I pasted everything that I thought could possibly be useful from chrome, hopefully it helps.

Also, I didn't see any DELETE requests when I was using the Chrome network tool, and I was seeing them on the other tool. Not sure if it matters, probably just a config option somewhere.

Comment: If we could see the network trace from the network tab in the Chrome inspector for a request that returns the OPTIONS response, but does not then do the DELETE that is supposed to come after it, we could probably see what is missing from the OPTIONS response that causes the browser to abort the DELETE operation.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, I added some stuff to the question and pasted some stuff into the gist. I tried to add everything you wanted, but if there's anything missing please tell me and I'll add more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I haven't found an exact answer, but I've found a workaround.

As it turns out, it might have something to do with axios, and I've been searching for the wrong things in the last 3 days.

This thread helped me: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1428

I've added an `e.preventDefault()` to the onClick method I use for the delete button.
This fixed the problem, but doesn't redirect (I use `href={link}`), so I'm going to add a conditional render for react-router to redirect the page. I don't know of a better method so maybe give me some ideas. I'll edit if I have further troubles.